err.Translate(trans) only works if translator passed via param (go-playground/validator)
I'm trying to translate the validation errors message because I don't like the default error message. When I pass the trans variable via param from controllers to a helper (to handle validation error), err.Translate(trans) worked just like what I want.
Here is the controllers/handler
package handler

import (
    "base-trade-rest/api/request"
    "base-trade-rest/core/helpers"
    "base-trade-rest/core/model"
    "base-trade-rest/core/service"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    en "github.com/go-playground/locales/en"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    en_translations "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10/translations/en"
)

type ProductHandler struct {
    ProductService service.IProductService
    Validate       *validator.Validate
    Trans          ut.Translator
}

func NewProductHandler(productService service.IProductService) *ProductHandler {

    // NOTE: omitting allot of error checking for brevity
    en := en.New()
    uni := ut.New(en, en)

    // this is usually know or extracted from http 'Accept-Language' header
    // also see uni.FindTranslator(...)
    trans, _ := uni.GetTranslator("en")

    validate := validator.New()
    en_translations.RegisterDefaultTranslations(validate, trans)

    var productHandler = ProductHandler{
        ProductService: productService,
        Validate:       validate,
        Trans:          trans,
    }
    return &productHandler
}

func (h *ProductHandler) Store(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var request request.ProductCreateRequest

    err := ctx.ShouldBind(&request)
    if err != nil {
        helpers.CreateFailedResponse(ctx, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = h.Validate.Struct(request)
    if err != nil {
        helpers.HandleValidationError(ctx, err, h.Trans)
        return
    }


    // Get authenticated user
    userData := helpers.GetAuthUser(ctx)

    product := model.Product{
        Name:     request.Name,
        ImageURL: nil,
        UserID:   userData.ID,
    }

    newUser, err := h.ProductService.CreateProduct(&product)
    if err != nil {
        helpers.CreateFailedResponse(ctx, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    helpers.CreateSuccessfulResponse(ctx, http.StatusOK, "Product successfully created", newUser)
}

And the helpers
package helpers

import (
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)


func getValidationErrors(err error, trans ut.Translator) map[string]string {
    var errors = make(map[string]string)

    errs := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
    for _, e := range errs {
        errors[strings.ToLower(e.Field())] = e.Translate(trans)
    }

    return errors
}


func HandleValidationError(ctx *gin.Context, err error, trans ut.Translator) {
    CreateValidationErrorResponse(ctx, getValidationErrors(err, trans))
}

The getValidationErrors()  returns just like i expected
{
    "name": "Name is a required field"
}

But because i dont want to repeat the code in every controllers/handlers, i created a helper and init the trans there
package helpers

import (
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    en "github.com/go-playground/locales/en"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    en_translations "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10/translations/en"
)

// use single instances, it caches struct info
var trans ut.Translator

func init() {
    en := en.New()
    uni := ut.New(en, en)
    trans, _ = uni.GetTranslator("en")

    validate := validator.New()
    en_translations.RegisterDefaultTranslations(validate, trans)
}

func getValidationErrors(err error) map[string]string {
    var errors = make(map[string]string)

    errs := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
    for _, e := range errs {
        errors[strings.ToLower(e.Field())] = e.Translate(trans)
    }

    return errors
}

func HandleValidationError(ctx *gin.Context, err error) {
    CreateValidationErrorResponse(ctx, getValidationErrorsTest(err))
}

And call it from controllers like this without passing the h.Trans
err = h.Validate.Struct(request)
if err != nil {
        helpers.HandleValidationError(ctx, err)
return
}

But it returns something like this which i don't want
{
    "name": "Key: 'ProductCreateRequest.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag"
}

I have tried changing init() but the result is still the same
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"
    en "github.com/go-playground/locales/en"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    en_translations "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10/translations/en"
)

// use single instances, it caches struct info
var trans ut.Translator

func init() {
    if v, ok := binding.Validator.Engine().(*validator.Validate); ok {
        en := en.New()
        uni := ut.New(en, en)

        var o bool
        trans, o = uni.GetTranslator("en")
        if !o {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("uni.GetTranslator(%s) failed", "en"))
        }

        err := en_translations.RegisterDefaultTranslations(v, trans)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        return
    }
}

Is there something i missed or is this a wrong way?
